# Data Nucleus many-many attributed relation with annotations

Tags: java, orm, jdo, datanucleus

I am trying to get a many-many attributed relationship working with DataNucleus and trying to do it with annotations.  I see from various examples [here](https://github.com/datanucleus/samples-jdo/blob/master/many_to_many_attributed/src/main/resources/org/datanucleus/samples/jdo/many_many_attributed/package.jdo) and [here](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_3/jdo/guides/many_to_many_attributed.html) that is can be done with xml.  Is there an example with annoations?  I know I need a  @Persistent(mappedBy="foo") on either side of the M-N but I wasnt sure if there is an annotation way of specifying the intermediate associative class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All metadata elements in general have an annotation. @Element if you want to specify info about the collection element, but clearly if you use generics then that is not needed.

Comment: Thanks.  You are right, It doesnt appear I need @Element with generics